# Adding Error Message to Input Text using javascript/jquery in Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, jquery, inputtext

My requirement is , I wanna add an error message to field seems like standard error only using apex , I don't wanna make them required. Should be like:

[image]

Update:

Apex Class:

```
public class MyController1 {
    Account account;
    public PageReference save() {
        try {
            update account;
        } catch (DmlException ex) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return 'MyController';
    }
    public Account getAccount() {
        if (account == null) account = [select id, name, numberofemployees, numberoflocations__c from Account where id =: ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
        return account;
    }
}
```

Page

```
<apex:page controller="MyController1" tabStyle="Account">
    <apex:messages />
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Hello {!$User.FirstName}!">
        This is your new page for the {!name} controller. <br/>
        You are viewing the {!account.name} account.

        <p>Number of Locations: <apex:inputField value="{!account.NumberofLocations__c}"
            id="Location_validation"/>
        (Enter an alphabetic character here, then click save to see what happens.) </p>

        <p>Number of Employees: <apex:inputField value="{!account.NumberOfEmployees}"
            id="Employee_validation"/>
        (Enter an alphabetic character here, then click save to see what happens.) </p>
            <p />
        <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
         <p />
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: have you tried with  field.addError method https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm ?

Comment: Hello Ratan,
    Actually, I have tried but I don't want an error of that type I need to add an error that seems like, the error come when we create an Account record nd forgot to enter 'Account Name'.

Comment: using addError method you can add the error message to specific field you just need to rerender that field in vf page..

Comment: will you please code it for me ... cause I've tried lots of code...

Comment: Please Post the code that what you have tried. So that we can say what to modify in it....

Comment: @AkshAy instead I suggest share your code piece of code and let me check what you are missing

Comment: public class MyController1 {
    Account account;

    public PageReference save() {
    try{
        update account;
    }
    catch(DmlException ex){
        ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
    }
    return null;
    }

    public String getName() { 
        return 'MyController';
    }

    public Account getAccount() {
        if(account == null)
        account = [select id, name, numberofemployees, numberoflocations__c from Account
        where id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
        return account;

    }
}

Comment: @Ratan I have sent you a mail Please check... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the code that will work with addError methdod

`account.NumberOfEmployees.addError('You must enter a value.');` this way you can add error message on field level ..

Page

```
<apex:page controller="AddErrorCtrl" tabStyle="Account">
    <apex:messages />
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Hello {!$User.FirstName}!" id="pblock">
        This is your new page for the {!name} controller. <br/>
        You are viewing the {!account.name} account.

        <p>Number of Locations: <apex:inputField value="{!account.NumberofLocations__c}"
            id="Location_validation"/>
        (Enter an alphabetic character here, then click save to see what happens.) </p>

        <p>Number of Employees: <apex:inputField value="{!account.NumberOfEmployees}"
            id="Employee_validation"/>
        (Enter an alphabetic character here, then click save to see what happens.) </p>
            <p />
        <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" rerender="pblock"/>
         <p />
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public class AddErrorCtrl {
    Account account;

    public PageReference save() {
        if(account.NumberOfEmployees == null)
        {
            account.NumberOfEmployees.addError('You must enter a value.');
            return null;
        }
        if(account.NumberofLocations__c == null)
        {
            account.NumberofLocations__c.addError('You must enter a value.');
            return null;
        }
        try{
            update account;
        }
        catch(DmlException ex){
            ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return 'MyController';
    }

    public Account getAccount() {
        if(account == null)
        account = [select id, name, numberofemployees, numberoflocations__c from Account
        where id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
        return account;

    }
}
```

### Updates: Validate fields using Jquery

```
<apex:page controller="AddErrorCtrl" tabStyle="Account">
    <style>
    .error{ border:1px solid red !important;}
    .messageClass{color: red; display: inline; float: right;position: absolute;margin: 3px;font-size:11px}
    </style>
    <apex:messages />
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Hello {!$User.FirstName}!" id="pblock">
        This is your new page for the {!name} controller. <br/>
        You are viewing the {!account.name} account.

        <p>
            Number of Locations: <apex:inputText value="{!account.NumberofLocations__c}" id="Location_validation"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            Number of Employees: <apex:inputText value="{!account.NumberOfEmployees}" id="Employee_validation"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="button" value=" Save " onclick="validateFields();" class="btn"/>
            <apex:actionFunction action="{!save}" name="SaveAF" rerender="pblock" />
        </p>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.js" ></script>
        <script>
            var isValidate = true;
            function validateFields()
            {
                var varFieldlist = ["Location_validation",  "Employee_validation"];
                validateRequiredFields(varFieldlist);
                if(isValidate)
                {
                    SaveAF();
                }
            }
            function validateRequiredFields(arrayFields){
                $.each( arrayFields, function( i, val ) {
                    if($('[id$='+val+']').val() =='')
                    {
                        if(!$('[id$='+val+']').hasClass('error'))
                        {
                            $('[id$='+val+']').addClass('error');
                            $('[id$='+val+']').after("<p class='messageClass' id="+'__'+val+"> Required </p>");
                            isValidate = false;
                        }
                    }
                    else if($('[id$='+val+']').hasClass('error'))
                    {
                        $('[id$='+val+']').removeClass('error');
                        $('[id$=__'+val+']' ).remove();
                        isValidate = true;
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

Comment: I wanna use <apex:inputText>....not the <apex:inputField>.

Comment: @AkshAy using inputText you can't do that, inorder to achieve this you need ajavascript else just go with apex:inputField.. Any reason for not using apex:inputField

Comment: @Ratan....will you please help me out with this Please And ya there is reason that's why m still trying

Comment: yes coz there is a requirment .... for that case

Comment: Ya you can ask reason is that I have a visualforce page simple page nd I wanna add an error to specific field but the field shouldn't be input field... so please tell me the way via javascript that you are thinking I wanna see that... :)

Comment: @AkshAy check my updates.... I am using jquery to validate fields

Comment: Can You Please Share Controller also

Comment: @AkshAy controler is same as above..

Comment: But In my org It is mot working... :(

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me  ... :) now it is working.. :)

Comment: @AkshAy glad I could help... Please accept this answer as best.. If you don't know how to accept an answer please visit help Center http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Sure Ratan your r really very helpFull thanks once again :)

Answer (score 1):

```
account.NumberOfEmployees.addError('You must enter a value.');
```

this way you can add error message on field level ..as per your requirement