# How to display error messaages in visualforce pages based on field value conditions

Tags: error-messages

I have a VF page on VF page.There are few validation rules on Opportunity object,Which are throwing as exceptions after clicking on save.Instead i want to display error on VF page.

VF page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="CreateOppExtension"  >
  <apex:sectionHeader title="Opportunity Edit" subtitle="New Opportunity Edit"/>

    <apex:form id="theForm" >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Opportunity Edit" mode="save">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" />
                <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
                       <apex:outputPanel styleClass="red" layout="block" >

                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Name}"/>
                     <apex:outputText value="{!Owner}" label="Oppourtunity Owner" />
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Opportunity_Type__c}" required="true"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Process_Quadrant__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Start_Date__c}" />
                    <br/> 
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.CloseDate}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Customer_Group_ERP__c}" required="true"/>
                    <br/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Device__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.PM_I_Business_Field__c}" required="true"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Node_Size__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Main_Group_GPH1__c}" required="true" />
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.TopProject__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Product__c}"/>
                    <br/> 
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.USP__c}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>

                <apex:pageBlockSection title="References" columns="2" collapsible="false">
                 <font color="#000000">
                     <apex:facet name="header">
                          <span style="color:black">References </span>
                     </apex:facet>
                 </font>  
                    <apex:inputField label="Account Name" value="{!opportunity.AccountId}" required="true"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.R_D_Project__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Master_Account__c}" />
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Project_ID__c}"/>
                    <br/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.NBD_ID__c}"/>                        
                 </apex:pageBlockSection>

                <apex:pageBlockSection title="Sales Cycle" columns="2" collapsible="false">
                 <font color="#000000">
                     <apex:facet name="header">
                          <span style="color:black">Sales Cycle</span>
                     </apex:facet>
                 </font>  
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.StageName}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Monthly_Progress__c}" required="true"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Status__c}" />        
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Counter_Measures__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Reason_PM_I__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Price_EUR_Unit__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Sub_Reason__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Dispense_Volume_mUnit__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Probability}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Layers__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Expected_Rev_rHVM__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Unit__c}"/> 
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Exp_Sales_Vol_p_a_EUR__c}"/>  
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.R_D_Headcount__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.PMI_In_Forecast__c}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Controller:

```
public class CreateOppExtension 
{
    Opportunity opp{set;get;}
    List<Opportunity> opp1 {set;get;}
    String Owner {get;set;}
    public id AccountId;



    public CreateOppExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController)
      {   
      //  GstdController= stdController;
        opp = (Opportunity)stdController.getRecord();
         opp.Notes__c = 'Testing is done in this Profile,It should be visible for only PM-I record type.';

         opp.AccountId =apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('AccountId');
         opp.Master_Account__c=apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('AccountId');

        }


    public PageReference save() {
        insert opp;

         Pagereference ref= new PageReference('/'+opp.Id);
                            return ref;

    }

    public String getowner()
     {
         Owner= UserInfo.getName();
         return owner;
     }

}
```

Validation rules:

Counter measures- `IF( AND( Counter_Measures__c="", RecordTypeId='012b0000000M8s5', ISPICKVAL(Monthly_Progress__c, "Red") ) , true, false)`

Reason-

```
RecordType.Id == '012b0000000M8s5' && NOT(ISPICKVAL( Status__c ,'Open')) && ISPICKVAL(Reason_PM_I__c,'') && NOT(CONTAINS($Profile.Name, "Administrator"))
```

Please find the exceptions errors. [image]

[image]

Please help how to acheive to display the error on page,based on conditions of validation rules.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<apex:pageMessages/>`

[More here ->](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_messages.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can do with help of `<apex:messages />`

place `<apex:messages />`  in visual force Page.

In Apex controller  pass the error message, example Like below .

```
ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING,'Please enter value'));
```

Comment: In Controller i have added                                                                                                        public PageReference save() {
        if(opp.Monthly_Progress__c == 'Red' && opp.RecordTypeId =='012b0000000M8s5' )
        {
          ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING,'Enter Counter Measure when Monthly Progress = Red.'));                                                              

        }
        insert opp;
        
         Pagereference ref= new PageReference('/'+opp.Id);

Comment: <apex:messages /> in VF page It is not working

Comment: Please updated the question what u have tried. usually it is working

Answer (score 0):

@Diljaan Shaik Hey you can use javascript function to show error message on the input field.
You can view this link for better idea [Adding Error Message to Input Text using javascript/jquery in Visualforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/120794/adding-error-message-to-input-text-using-javascript-jquery-in-visualforce)